# Search if specific elements are already in a ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a list with grades, subjects and years, but I want to make it so it checks if there is a grade already for a given subject and year, and I can't figure out how to search for it in the list.

```
public List<Nota> notas;
public Double notaMedia;

//Constructor
public ExpedienteImpl() {
    this.notas = new ArrayList<Nota>();
    this.notaMedia = getNotaMedia();
}

private void checkNota(Integer cursoAcademico, TipoConvocatoria tipoConvocatoria, Asignatura asignatura){
    if (this.notas.contains()){

    }
}
```

Something like this is what I have done, but the contains only works with one object (?) and I want to search if there is anything in the Nota field for a given cursoAcademico, tipoConvocatoria and asignatura (course, subject).

Nota's code:

```
public interface Nota {

Asignatura getAsignatura();

Integer getCursoAcademico(); //Dado por el primer aÃ±o del curso, eg: 2014/15 -> 2014

TipoConvocatoria getTipoConvocatoria(); //Primero, segundo o tercero

Double getValorNota();
TipoNota getTipoNota(); //0-5 Supenso, 5-7 Aprobado, 7-9 Notable, 9-10 Sobresaliente, 9-10 + menciÃ³n = MatrÃ­cula de Honor,  
Boolean getMencionHonor();


}

public class NotaImpl implements Nota {

//Atributos
private Integer cursoAcademico;
private TipoConvocatoria tipoConvocatoria;
private Double valorNota;
private TipoNota tipoNota;
private Boolean mencionHonor;
private Asignatura asignatura;

//Constructores
public NotaImpl(Asignatura asignatura, Integer cursoAcademico, TipoConvocatoria tipoConvocatoria, Double valorNota, TipoNota tipoNota, Boolean mencionHonor) {
    checkerNumero(valorNota);
    checkerMencion(mencionHonor, valorNota);
    this.cursoAcademico = cursoAcademico;
    this.tipoConvocatoria = tipoConvocatoria;
    this.tipoNota = tipoNota;
    this.valorNota = valorNota;
    this.mencionHonor = mencionHonor;
}
```

Not sure if you need more.

Comment: Please post `Nota`´s code.

Comment: I have no idea what a `HashList` is.

Comment: What fields and methods are in your `Nota` class?

Comment: Not that I can imagine: after all, your set contains elements of the type Nota, not of the type Integer, TipoConvocatoria, ...
Look a bit into an implementation of the equals method in your Nota class, and create for each search an instance which you pass to the contains method.

Comment: Maybe everything I'm doing is completely wrong? Fixed @chrylis

Comment: how do you think 'contains' will be matching the elements ? you need to overwrite the equals and hashcode methods. depending on the implementation of equals, you 'll be able to create what you need, as I said in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through the list, get the object and compare it.
Easiest would be to create a nota object with marks etc.
Override the equals method of Nota.

Now,
Use contais to check if it presents.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpedienteImpl {

    public List<Nota> notas;
    public Double notaMedia;

    //Constructor
    public ExpedienteImpl() {
        this.notas = new ArrayList<Nota>();
        this.notaMedia = getNotaMedia();
    }

    private Double getNotaMedia() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private void checkNota(Integer cursoAcademico, TipoConvocatoria tipoConvocatoria, Asignatura asignatura){
        Nota objNota = new NotaImpl(asignatura, cursoAcademico, tipoConvocatoria, 0.0, null, null);
        if(notas.contains(objNota)){
                System.out.println("Nota matched");
        }
    }

}

interface Nota {

Asignatura getAsignatura();

Integer getCursoAcademico(); //Dado por el primer aÃ±o del curso, eg: 2014/15 -> 2014

TipoConvocatoria getTipoConvocatoria(); //Primero, segundo o tercero

Double getValorNota();
TipoNota getTipoNota(); //0-5 Supenso, 5-7 Aprobado, 7-9 Notable, 9-10 Sobresaliente, 9-10 + menciÃ³n = MatrÃ­cula de Honor,  
Boolean getMencionHonor();


}

class NotaImpl implements Nota {

//Atributos
private Integer cursoAcademico;
private TipoConvocatoria tipoConvocatoria;
private Double valorNota;
private TipoNota tipoNota;
private Boolean mencionHonor;
private Asignatura asignatura;

//Constructores
public NotaImpl(Asignatura asignatura, Integer cursoAcademico, TipoConvocatoria tipoConvocatoria, Double valorNota, TipoNota tipoNota, Boolean mencionHonor) {
    checkerNumero(valorNota);
    checkerMencion(mencionHonor, valorNota);
    this.cursoAcademico = cursoAcademico;
    this.tipoConvocatoria = tipoConvocatoria;
    this.tipoNota = tipoNota;
    this.valorNota = valorNota;
    this.mencionHonor = mencionHonor;
}

private void checkerMencion(Boolean mencionHonor2, Double valorNota2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void checkerNumero(Double valorNota2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Asignatura getAsignatura() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Integer getCursoAcademico() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public TipoConvocatoria getTipoConvocatoria() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Double getValorNota() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public TipoNota getTipoNota() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Boolean getMencionHonor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public boolean equals(Nota nota){
    if(this.getCursoAcademico().equals(nota.getCursoAcademico()))
        return true;
    return false;
}
}


class Asignatura{
}

class TipoConvocatoria{

}

class TipoNota{

}
```

Update the equals method in such a way that if satisfied your equality criteria.

Comment: So I could make a 'small list' with the object that I want to compare, then loop through the other list and use the equals each time? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If he implements equals according to his requirements, why iterating over the List ? The contains method would work just fine.

Comment: @BrickTop You don't need another list. Just a temporary object for the comparison and you don't need to iterate over it by yourself. Use `List#contains` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through whole list and then compare fields of each object with the param.

Comment: The point is not to iterate over the List, just by calling a method (like) contains.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 the Stream API:s may be of use here.

```
// Filter out all Nota-objects that match the provided input
// and store them in a list
final List<Nota> filtered = this.notas.stream()
    .filter(nota -> {
        return nota.getCursoAcademico().equals(cursoAcademico) &&
                nota.getTipoConvocatoria().equals(tipoConvocatoria) &&
                nota.getAsignatura().equals(asignatura);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Or, count the number of matching objects
final long count = this.notas.stream()
    .filter(nota -> {
        return nota.getCursoAcademico().equals(cursoAcademico) &&
               nota.getTipoConvocatoria().equals(tipoConvocatoria) &&
               nota.getAsignatura().equals(asignatura);
    })
    .count();
```

This way you can filter out your matches provided that the `TipoConvocatoria` and `Asignatura` has equals methods.

You can read more about streams [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and you can especially check out the `filter`-method.

Answer (score 0):

In C# this would be:

```
public class Grade{
    public int Mark { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Now lets say you have some data

```
var grades = new List<Grade>()
{
    new Grade() {Mark = 3, Subject = "Calculus II", Year = 2015},
    new Grade() {Mark = 2, Subject = "Calculus II", Year = 2014}
};
var grade = new Grade() {Mark = 10, Subject = "Calculus II", Year = 2015};
```

If you want to check if grade with same Subject and Year exists you would write:

```
if (!grades.Any(o => o.Subject == grade.Subject && o.Year == grade.Year))
{//does not exists - add
    grades.Add(grade);
}
else
{//exists

}
```

In Java 1.4, 1.5, 6, 7 you do not have lambda's and writing this would be somewhat cumbersome as it requires quite a bit of boilerplate code. However there is [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) formally known as Google Collections, that add support for this up to java 6 (it used to be up to java 1.5, but not sure atm.). There is also an alternative called Appache Collections that for the most part do the same thing a bit differently.

In any case you write

```
Predicate<Integer> isEven = new Predicate<Grade>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(Grade item) {
        return item.Subject == grade.Subject && item.Year == grade.Year;
    }               
};
if (Iterables.filter(grades, isEven).isEmpty())
{//does not exists - add
    grades.Add(grade);
}
else
{//exists

}
```

This abuses the variable scope visibility of anonymous functions in Java, but it is very clean and easy to read, has great performance and should work up to Java 1.5. If iterables do not have **.isEmpty()**, it is about same as **.size()<=0**. (Sadly I do not get paid for writing Java, so do not have dev environment ready to check, this was just written from memory).